# Match and retrieve multiple values from the string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I need to match couple of numbers from the stdout and retrieve them from the string, string can look like this (multiple variations):

```
"Finished in 1 hour 13 minutes 46 seconds (files took 2.18 seconds to load)"
"Finished in 13 minutes 46 seconds (files took 2.18 seconds to load)"
"Finished in 46 seconds (files took 2.18 seconds to load)"
```

How can I match these numbers by one regular expression? I tried multiple way but none of them is getting me what I need.

```
string = "...[one of the above]"
match = string.match(/[different variations of regex]/)
```

Or I also tried:

```
match = string.scan(/[different variations of regex]/)
```

I am personally not good with regex, any ideas?

Expected output would be:

```
match[0] = 1 hour
match[1] = 13 minutes
match[2] = 46 seconds
```

Thanks to @anubhava I got myself a solution.
Solution:

```
match = string.scan(/(?:^|\s)(\d+ (?:hour|seconds|minutes)\b)/)
```

Which produces:

```
[["1 hour"], ["13 minutes"], ["46 seconds"]]
```

Final implementation:

```
t.scan(/Finished\s+in\s+(?:(?<hour>\d+)\s+hours?\s+)?(?:(?<minute>\d+)\s+minutes?\s+)?(?<second>\d+)\s+seconds?/)
```

Which produces:

```
[["1"], ["13"], ["46"]]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Why you don't want to match `2.18 seconds` ?

Comment: That information have no value for me at this moment.

Comment: i don't know what you mean by the above comment.

Comment: No worries @AvinashRaj I already solved it with the regex suggested bellow, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Finished\s+in\s+(?:(?<hour>\d+)\s+hours?\s+)?(?:(?<minute>\d+)\s+minutes?\s+)?(?<second>\d+)\s+seconds?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/MI0Zpncz1H)

Comment: This is a better answer, because the numbers for hours/minutes/seconds are always in the same capture group. As well this regex accepts both `hour` and `hours`, `minutes` and `minute`, etc. (notice the **s**)

Comment: Thank you, that is true, that gives me quite an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)? (hour|seconds|minutes)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/xIH0WBl2uL)

In case you don't want to match floating point values then use:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d+ (?:hour|seconds|minutes)\b)
```

Comment: Did you check the rugby regex demo link I provided?

Comment: Yes I did and as soon as I used scan instead of match, it worked, thank you very much. Appreciate it.